# Transaction stuck because of "Dust"?

Tags: transactions, dust

been waiting 8 days for this transaction because Bitcoincore couldn't be arsed working out the network fees.  Not a big transaction, but has caused a lot of grief because recipient now thinks I'm dishonest, even though I sent again from an online wallet which went through !!

if anyone can help the transaction ID is 
7fb10192748c0cea3d441a98789086d9905c6d83de11bc19b716b4be6ade5c04

I don't even mind if it is confirmed and sent to original vendor as, at least, my reputation will be restored

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You used a fee-rate of 6 sat/B. Even though fees have dropped drastically over the week, that's about factor ten too little to confirm. Additionally, one of your outputs will cost its own value to spend at 3 sat/B. Even at today's exchange rate it's only worth about 1.5¢, you should try to avoid creating outputs that small as they're unspendable burnt money. That's the output that triggered the dust categorization.